# yum client not reflecting state of the server

Tags: yum, rhel

I am trying to setup a local yum repo and have religiously followed the steps as Click [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/create-your-own-yum-repository/).It seems to be working fine. But the only problem on when i add new rpm to this repo. executed "yum makecache" and it returns "Metadata file does not match checksum"

Comment: Have you already tried out `yum clean all`?

Comment: Perhaps see [CentOS - Yum doesn't update anymore?](http://superuser.com/q/565063)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due caching and the cache was due to a http caching. have added "http_caching=none" in yum.conf file.Thus the yum doesn't cache any of the information and retrieves the same from the server.If you still want to use htpp caching you have to wait until the cache times out.